# RegExp is not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing some function that switches urls into their embed url.
So, I have a two-dimensional array that has the original url and the embed url.

I'm trying to use RegExp to make sure this is a valid URL, but it just won't work..

This is a code that worked:

```
arr[x].match(/^(http:\/\/){0,1}(www.){0,1}(allmyvideos.net\/){1}([a-z0-9])+$/ig);
```

While this code won't work:

```
var sites = [
    ["allmyvideos.net/VIDID", "allmyvideos.net/embed-VIDID"]
];
var arr = document.getElementById('original').value.split("\n");
for(var x in arr)
{
    var regex = new RegExp("/^(http:\/\/){0,1}(www.){0,1}(" + sites[0][0].replace("VIDID", "").replace(/[\/]/g, "\\/") + "){1}([a-z0-9])+$/ig");
    regex.test(arr[x]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here that the second approach is not working?

Comment: Where is `arr` and `x` defined?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it, one second.

Comment: i think your `.replace(/[\/]/g, "\\/")` should be `.replace(/[\/]/g, "\/")` but we cant really help until you show us some intermediate steps, like the output of `arr[x].match(regex)` or the final string that you pass into `new RegExp()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new RegExp()` constructor form doesn't use the surrounding `/` characters:

```
var re = new RegExp("thing to check", "ig");
re.test("THING to CHECK")
// => true
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the escapes in the string. :)